# Exempt some delegate methods in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, delegates

I'm facing an issue with delegate, I have 3 different TextFields in storyboard,

1. Name - (IBOutlet - txtName)
2. Phone Number  - (IBOutlet - txtPhone)
3. Email - (IBOutlet - txtEmail)

What I'm trying, to restrict the user not to type Number while typing Name, same for Phone Number, want to restrict the User not to type Character other than Number.

So what I'm trying to using delegate method :

```
self.txtName.delegate = self;

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *charOnly = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                              [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"] invertedSet]]
                             componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return [string isEqualToString:charOnly];
}
```

But I want both the field - Name and Phone Number to be restricted on same form. So if do

```
self.txtPhone.delegate = self
```

it calls `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` while typing which restrict only for Alphabets.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *numOnly = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                              [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234567890"] invertedSet]]
                             componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return [string isEqualToString:numOnly];
}
```

As i did in jQuery, to assign class name to field and implemented in following way:

```
<input type='text' class='numValid'>
$(".numValid").keypress(function(event) 
{
});
<input type='text' class='nameValid'>
$(".nameValid").keypress(function(event) 
{
});
```

Is there similar way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate method returns the textfield that is being edited, so use that to know how to apply the correct logic.

```
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
   BOOL isValid = YES;
   if (textField == self.txtName) {
      //name validation
   } else if (textField == self.txtPhone) {
     //number validation
   }
   return isValid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks James P , just before having your answer i just found same while searching for this issue. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are better off specifying in storyboard editor that the textfield
is a phone type and let ios do the checking. One reason for that
is because user will get a better keyboard for text entry,
another is that ios will do it correctly allowing + prefix in addition to digits.

As for the name field I'd won't do any restriction on it if I were you.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but i want to restrict the user and i want to know how to achieve it ?

Comment: See, voting down on a question which, once implemented, would surely infuriate users requires 125 reputation, so folks such as myself have to provide you with a detailed answer why doing it the way you are planning to is an awful idea in the first place. It might be acceptable on android but doing the validation the way you want on ios will raise more than a few eyebrows, sigh